# How to access my template variable in base template file in Symfony

Tags: symfony, breadcrumbs

My Controller action

```
public function viewAction() {
        $breadcrumbs = array();
        $breadcrumbs = array("Home"=>$this->get("router")->generate("admin_home"));
$breadcrumbs = array("View"=>'');
       $this->render('UserBundle:Default:view.html.twig',array('breadcrumbs'=>$breadcrumbs));
}
```

This is my View template and "breadcrumbs" array here is accessible here.

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
<section class="content">
{{ dump(breadcrumbs) }}
</div>
{% endblock body %}
```

This is my Base template file but i am not able to access breadcrumbs here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>......
<section>
<div class="breadcrumb">
{{ dump(breadcrumbs) }}
</div>
</section>
{% block body %}{% endblock %}
```

Note :- I don't want to use any bundle for breadcrumbs.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a block in `base.html.twig`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>......
<section>
<div class="breadcrumb">
{% block breadcrumb %}{% endblock %}
</div>
</section>
{% block body %}{% endblock %}
```

and fill it in *child* template just like the `body` block:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
    <section class="content">
    (...) //content
    </div>
{% endblock body %}
{% block breadcrumb %}
    {{ dump(breadcrumbs) }}
{% endblock breadcrumb %}
```

**EDIT**
Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17244162/symfony2-twig-how-can-i-send-parameters-to-the-parent-template) may help you, but I didn't test it with current Twig version.

Comment: Your approach is great but i have to put this code in every template. Is there any other option to put my code once in layout like cakephp , yii frameworks.

Comment: It probably could be done with some kind of custom Twig extension that would produce breadcrumbs on its own. That could be even more comfortable than doing it in controller and passing to Twig template. But it depends on how you create breadcrumb's content.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `render(controller(...))` for this.

### Controller:

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        // replace this example code with whatever you need
        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', [
            'breadcrumbs' => [
                'home' => 'home_url',
                'view' => 'view_url',
            ],
        ]);
    }

    public function breadcrumbsAction(array $breadcrumbs = []) {
        return $this->render('AppBundle::breadcrumbs.html.twig', [
            'breadcrumbs' => $breadcrumbs
        ]);
    }
}
```

### base.html.twig

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
        {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" />
    </head>
    <body>
        {{ render(controller('AppBundle:Default:breadcrumbs', { 'breadcrumbs': breadcrumbs })) }}
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
        {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

### breadcrumbs.html.twig

```
{{ dump(breadcrumbs) }}
```

UPDATE: made breadcrumbs dynamic

Comment: Breadcrumbs never be fixed. We have to change on every page. How could you change by rending controller in view file ?