# Overriding base template variables to child template from another bundle {Symfony 3 TWIG}

Tags: php, twig, symfony

I have added some of the variables in **base.html.twig** file 
I have another file **index.html.twig** file in "bundle"

I have extended **base.html.twig** file in **index.html.twig** which is working fine as I am able to see all content in base is rendered in browser when i am calling **index.html.twig**, but when i try to override variables of **base.html.twig** file from **index.html.twig** its not working

here is code

**base.html.twig**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8" />
                <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
                {% block stylesheets %}

                {% endblock %}
                <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon') }}" />
            </head>
            <body>
           {% set isHeader      = (isHeader|default(true)) %}

{% if isHeader == true %}
            <div class="container-fluid header">
                {% include 'header.html.twig' %}
                {% block header %}

                {% endblock %}
            </div>
            {% endif %}

    </body>
    </html>
```

**index.html.twig**

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% set isHeader         = false %}
```

this should hide header but its still displaying header where as if I do isHeader = false in **base.html.twig** file it works fine

Comment: Try to not use `set` in parent template:  `{% if isHeader|default(true) == true %}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony2 - Twig - How can I send parameters to the parent template?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17244162/symfony2-twig-how-can-i-send-parameters-to-the-parent-template)

Comment: I have tried this link but not working for me :(

Comment: @malcolm thanks for reply i have tried your trick also but its also not working

Comment: Yes it not working, strange behavior. I tried as well, only if I put values into brackets (as strings) it works:  `{% set var = 'true' %}` `{% if var|default('false') == 'true' %}` It must be a bug, because  I dumped variable in parent template and it set correctly from child. It worked in Symfony 2 until now.

Comment: Thanks for the help I an work with string variables :)

Answer (score 5):

your method is too weird , i'm not sure why are you doing this , 
According to what I found from question , try to do something like this :

in base :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8" />
            <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
            {% block stylesheets %}

            {% endblock %}
            <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon') }}" />
        </head>
        <body>
       {%block top_header %}
            <div class="container-fluid header">
               {% include 'header.html.twig' %}
                {% block header %}

                {% endblock %}
            </div>
        {%endblock%}
</body>
</html>
```

in index :

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block top_header %}{% endblock %} //keep this empty , remove the top_header content
```

Comment: <div class="container-fluid header">
                {% include 'header.html.twig' %}
                {% block header %}

                {% endblock %}
            </div>
if i do as you suggest i have included one file in header block which will render by default i dont want to render that part also..

also this is not convenient way for me to add empty blocks each time when i create new bundle and do tempating rather i will do variables true/false that can be configured from DB also.

Comment: My question is simple I want to set variables of parent scope in child scope so that when twig is getting rendered it can use child scope variables for decision making i.e. to remove or show hide blocks + setting bootstrap grid size accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I found answer by setting global for twig in **symfony config.yml** file here is code

**config.yml**

```
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
    globals:
        isFooter: true
        isHeader: true
```

**base.html.twig**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8" />
            <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon') }}" />
        </head>

        <body>
    {% if isHeader == true %}
        <div class="container-fluid header">
        {% include 'header.html.twig' %}
            {% block header %}

            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    {% endif %}

{% block body %}

{% endblock %}

    {% if isFooter == true %}
        <div class="footer">
        {% include 'footer.html.twig' %}
            {% block footer %}

            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    {% endif %}

    <noscript><div class="alert alert-danger">You must enable Javascript on your browser for the site to work optimally and display sections completely.</div></noscript>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**index.html.twig**

```
{% set isFooter         = true %}
{% set isHeader         = false %}

{% block body %}

{% endblock %}
```

variable isHeader = false will remove header from base template so that it will not render on call of index.html.twig

**Any other workaround guys please comment your suggestions.**